# Cannot link SFML to my project in code::blocks

Tags: c++, sfml

If anybody uses SFML, could you tell me how to add it to a project in code::blocks? Any technique will do.

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Well,
If you did a basic google search, you would find lots of answers to your question.
Here is a good website to answer your question, straight from SFML itself: [SFML and Code::Blocks](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-cb.php)

This is based off of windows, but I'm sure it will work for all platforms.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already tried everything and nothing worked. If you have used it and/or know how to add it to a project tell me how to do it.

Comment: @Raj which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 7

Comment: Are you getting any errors of some sort trying to compile the program (If so, can you display them)? Or you just in general can't figure out how to link it?

Comment: Another thing, do you have the correct version of SFML for code::blocks (the MinGW GCC version)? Or do you have the correct bit version of it (32-bit or 64-bit)?